# How do I import a file from a folder in main?

Tags: rust

I have such a directory structure:

```
structs
    -book.rs
main.rs
```

I just read about modules and am trying to import a structure from *book.rs* in *main*:

**book.rs**

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct book{
    pub title:u32
}
```

**main.rs**

```
mod book;

fn main() {
   print!("start")
}
```

And this causes an error: `unresolved module, can't find module file: book.rs , or book/mod.rs`

I tried in different ways, but it doesn't work out. I will be glad of help to understand what the error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `structs` a module to be able to import things.

```
structs
    -book.rs
    -mod.rs
main.rs
```

`main.rs`

```rs
mod structs;
use crate::structs::book::book;

fn main() {
    let b = book {
        title: "The Rust Programming Language".to_string(),
    };
    print!("{:?}", b);
}
```

`structs/mod.rs`

```rs
pub mod book;
```

`structs/book.rs`

```rs
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct book{
    pub title: String,
}
```

You should also change `book` to be `Book` when you define the struct since structs should be in PascalCase not camelCase or snake_case

Comment: Is the use of mod.rs is not deprecated? Maybe I misunderstood , but it was written in the official guide

Comment: @Omegon `mod.rs` is not deprecated and is still favored by many.